# Get event name with socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm emitting socket :

```
socket.emit('test', {data : data})
```

And getting data

```
socket.on('test', function(data)  {
  ...
})
```

Can I get the event name(`test`) in `node.js`? (Without sending it as a paramater)

Comment: Sockets don't natively have a name.  What name is it that you want?

Comment: Sorry I noticed it's not name, it's event.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what you're asking for then.

Comment: Putting it in the payload might be the easiest for debugging, but you can always use closures. http://jsfiddle.net/7nh1zovz/